# Node Access Product Module (nap) - Really embarrassing error message

Tags: ubercart, users

I have built an Ubercart site, using the [Node Access Product](http://drupal.org/project/nap) module, that sells only two products, one of which is access to a single node. Everything works correctly, but after the customer makes a successful purchase the following errors are repeated all the down the completed order page:

"Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in nap_save_purchase() (line 1508 of /home/mysite/public_html/sites/all/modules/nap/nap.module)"

and

"Notice: Undefined index: type in drupal_write_record() (line 7025 of /home/mysite/public_html/includes/common.inc)"

I have been everywhere looking for an answer. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

This error is thrown when an object is empty, and you attempt to determine the value of a property. In this case the following code is responsible:

```
 // Go through each of the products purchased.
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($product_nodes); $i++) {
    // Easy referencing.
    $node = &$product_nodes[$i];
    $settings = nap_get_nap_settings($node->nid); <- Throws error
```

My guess is that $product_nodes is empty.

Try wrapping the for loop as follows:

```
 // Go through each of the products purchased.
  if (!empty($product_nodes)) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($product_nodes); $i++) {
      // Easy referencing.
      $node = &$product_nodes[$i];
      $settings = nap_get_nap_settings($node->nid);

      ..rest of loop code ...

    } //End of for loop
  }
```

This should work. You should also bring this up as an issue on the project page.

Comment: @Patrick Wire - This was already an [issue on D.O.](http://drupal.org/node/1936502). I know you are new to Drupal Answers, but if the answer helped, please indicate it by accepting the answer so other will know it has been solved. Otherwise please post a comment indicating that it did not work so we can look for other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

2 things.

- Somewhere in your code your saving something with a column `type` in
  a database table. It's probably in `nap_save_purchase()`. The field
  is blank when you save the record to the DB. fix that.
- You have all error messages likely going to the screen on your live website. You can hide Notice messages in your settings.php file with like `ini_set('error_reporting', 'E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE');`